# TheFatRat Installation Issues mingw-32 →NOT OK mingw-w64 → NOT OK

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, mingw-w64, mingw32, kali-linux

***TheFatRat Installation Issue... :-) [ mingw-32 & mingw-w64 ] (Plss Help Me with This... Tried All the things you discussed with others... Stuck with this from 3 days...) #244***

issue thread : https://github.com/Screetsec/TheFatRat/issues/244

SS issue :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/awjM2.png

this is doesn't work for me :
github link : https://github.com/Screetsec/TheFatRat/issues/244#issuecomment-366370454
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXnPZ.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

same solution just change the version to a compatible one :

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQz5t.png

go to /etc/apt and you will find sources.list

to change the file use :

```
sudo mousepad sources.list
```

or

```
sudo vim sources.list
```

then white the new packages :

The right ones are :

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
deb http://old.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib
deb-src http://old.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib

write these repositories in your sources list .
then after this open new terminal & write this in your terminal :
wget https://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/k/kali-archive-keyring/kali-archive-keyring_2020.2_all.deb && dpkg -i kali-archive-keyring_2020.2_all.deb

then , do the process all over again by installing mingw as it was written before .
```

**>> it works like a charm ! also works if you have kaliLinux 2020.3**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: then proceed to installation and it will works just fine]

[image]

***Good luck !***